# Is there a suggested maximum amount of words for a single sentence in academic writing?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, academia

For instance [the UK government generally suggests](https://insidegovuk.blog.gov.uk/2014/08/04/sentence-length-why-25-words-is-our-limit/) that 25 words is a good limit.
I find hard in academic writing to respect such limit, and 50 words seems more appropriate to me. But English is not my native language, and in Italian sentences are generally longer.
Do you know any good resource with suggestions or guidelines in this regard or do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: "..less is more.."

[from Andrea del Sarto, 1855, a poem by Robert Browning]

Comment: Academic writing is terrible writing.  Do not seek to emulate it if your intent is to communicate.  Any style of writing would be better.  Except legal. Lawyers don't want to be understood by anyone but the judge.

Comment: Since this question regards academic practices more-so than English prose, I would suggest that this question might be better asked on the [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) website. They'd be more likely to know than us, since they're the people most likely to adhere to academic restrictions on a regular basis. I also think it could be vaguely interpreted as a question regarding the "[… expectations of academicians](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". Cross-posting is forbidden on the S.E. network though. Would it be possible to migrate this question?

Answer (score 5):

Your concern should be how easy it is for a human reader to parse meaning out of your sentences, not the absolute length of a sentence. Long sentences  often induce parsing errors because phrasal heads are separated from their modifiers, and you eventually run into memory limitations. Take an example from Caro's biography of Robert Moses:

> Kern believes that Moses inspired and helped direct from behind the scenes not only the investigation, one of the viler chapters in New York political history (the committee took advantage of the association in the public mind of godless Communism with free love to drag into the hearing insinuations about Kern's love life), but also the public smear campaign against him of which the investigation was the centerpiece—and that the Park Commissioner's bloodhounds kept the investigators supplied with fresh ammunition.

This is one sentence, and it is hard to read because by the time you get to *the public smear campaign* you've forgotten that this is the object of *directed behind the scenes*. The sentence could stay the same length and be much easier to read if it were restructured for better parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I've done quite a bit of academic and technical writing myself. The goal is the same as for any other kind of writing: to say what you have to say as clearly and succinctly as possible.

Several years ago, I read *Several short sentences about writing,* by Verlyn Klinkenborg (Vintage Books, April 2013). The book's main points include:

- Keep your sentences short
- Avoid transitions as much as possible
- Make sure each of your sentences says what you intend it to say.

I have greatly improved my writing by following these simple rules.

*The maximum number of words for a single sentence in academic writing* shouldn't be a fixed number or target. Every sentence should say what it has to say in the smallest number of words possible. It should then leave the stage, having played its part.